# Javascript from one list to another

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one list which filling up from db is userlist as following;

```
<select id="Userlist" name="cars" runat="server" multiple="true" style="width: 270px; height: 200px;">
</select>
```

I want to add selected items from Userlist to the following list (ToChoose);

```
<select id="ToChoose" name="cars" multiple="multiple" style="width: 270px; height: 200px;"></select>

<input id="ButtonAddUsers" onclick="return validateUser();" type="button" value="Add" />
```

And this is my JS function. I tried with two function which has to work. I will share both.

```
function validateUser() {
            var selItem = document.getElementById("Userlist").selectedIndex;
            if (selItem == -1) {
                window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
            } else {
                document.getElementById("ToChoose").add(document.getElementById("Userlist")[selItem], null);
            }
}
```

The other one what i tried is;

```
           var user = document.getElementById("Userlist");
            var seluser = user.selectedIndex;

            if (seluser == -1) {
                window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
            }
            else {
                var toChoose = document.getElementById("ToChoose");
                var newOption = user[seluser].cloneNode(true);
                toChoose.appendChild(newOption);
            }
```

EDIT: This is how i fill up the Userlist from database;

```
        string mycommand = "SELECT [id], [username] FROM [users]";
        SqlDataAdapter x = new SqlDataAdapter(mycommand, ConnectionString);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        x.Fill(ds, "users");
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        Userlist.DataSource = dt;
        Userlist.DataTextField = "username";
        Userlist.DataValueField = "username";
        Userlist.DataBind();
```

Comment: And the question is?..

Comment: Good point, sorry i forgot the mention well. The question is why i am not able to insert this selected items from Userlist to ToChoose ? The functions is working when i tried online.You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/quj3vgza/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, maybe you could use the wrong Id of Userlist. If you post all your code in view, everybody can help you better.

Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

1) Create sample data in code behind

```
public partial class About : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dtName = new DataTable();

            //Add Columns to Table
            dtName.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DisplayMember"));
            dtName.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ValueMember"));

            //Now Add Values
            dtName.Rows.Add("Suits", "0");
            dtName.Rows.Add("Harvey Spector", "1");
            dtName.Rows.Add("Jessica Pearson", "2");
            dtName.Rows.Add("Mike Ross", "3");
            dtName.Rows.Add("Donna Paulson", "4");
            dtName.Rows.Add("Rachel", "5");

            //Bind data to Userlist     
            Userlist.DataSource = dtName;
            Userlist.DataTextField = dtName.Columns["DisplayMember"].ToString();
            Userlist.DataValueField = dtName.Columns["ValueMember"].ToString();
            Userlist.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

2) View

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormSample.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>

    <select id="Userlist" name="cars" runat="server" multiple="true" style="width: 270px; height: 200px;">
    </select>

    <select id="ToChoose" name="cars" multiple="multiple" style="width: 270px; height: 200px;"></select>

    <input id="ButtonAddUsers" onclick="return validateUser();" type="button" value="Add" />


    <script>
        function validateUser() {
            var selItem = document.getElementById("MainContent_Userlist").selectedIndex;
            if (selItem == -1) {
                window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
            } else {
                document.getElementById("ToChoose").add(document.getElementById("MainContent_Userlist")[selItem], null);
            }
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. My only missing thing was adding the MainContent to before Userlist. You save my days. All the best :)